# How to avoid other Ingress players to steal items when I am exchanging items with others?

Tags: ingress

It is very annoying that when I am dropping capsules to other Ingress members, someone steal it. I lose many items from this problem and I don't know what to do to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you can't. Arrange to meet the people you want to trade with somewhere quiet so you can be reasonably sure there's nobody else around.